# Laravel 5.2 pdf mime type validation issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am unable to validate pdf attachments (multi) , laravel 5.2. The validation rule is sth like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

class UploadRequest extends Request
{    
   public function rules()
   {   
    return [
                'attachments'=> 'required|mimes:pdf',
           ];
   }
}
```

or

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

class UploadRequest extends Request
{    
   public function rules()
   {
    return [
                'attachments'=> 'required|mimetypes:application/pdf',
           ];
   }
}
```

I am following as suggested in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-mimes). It invalidated all attachment types.

### Edit

I have to add custom validation mean while I get around this

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as ValidationFactory;

class UploadRequest extends Request
{    

    public function __construct(ValidationFactory $validationFactory)
    {
       $validationFactory->extend(
           'pdf',
           function ($attribute, $files, $parameters) {

               if(is_array($files)){
                   foreach($files as $file){
                       if($file->getMimeType()!='application/pdf'){
                           return false ;
                       }
                   }
               }else
                   return $files->getMimeType()=='application/pdf';
               return true;
           },
           'File is not a pdf document'
       );


    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
                    'attachments'=> 'required|pdf',
               ];
    }

   }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the rule, you must be doing something else wrong higher up in your code.

Comment: @fire you might be right :)

Answer (score 3):

You may use `'attachments.*' => 'required|mimes:pdf',`.

`*` character can be used for [validating arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays) (multi attachments here).

Answer (score 0):

```
use Validator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('pdf', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {
            $allowed_mimes = [
                'application/pdf', // pdf
            ];
            return in_array($value->getMimeType(), $allowed_mimes);
        });
    }

// and in the NewsletterRequest:
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'pdf_file' => 'pdf',
        ];
    }
```